# Windows Service unable to set language using CurrentCulture

Tags: c#, windows-services, currentculture, currentuiculture

I have a two resource files in my windows service for the purpose of localization (English and French). 
These resource files contain messages that I want to show the user after the service completes its task. The language in which I want to show these messages come from database (en/fr). I'm using `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` to set the languages.

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
```

If I run the service in DEBUG mode the language sets fine and if I set to `en` I get the messages in English and if I set it to `fr` I get the messages in French. But after installing the service (vs setup project) all the messages I get are in English whether I set it to `en` or `fr`

Are there any other settings for localization?

Comment: How did you get the localized strings? By default `ResourceManager` uses the satellite assemblies for every language

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I get the strings by `ResourceFileName.ResourceKeyName`. The access modifier for both files is set to `Public`. I also tried using the `ResourceManager.GetString()`, it didn't work either.

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999835/localizing-windows-service. Windows Service can't find the satellite assembly, it needs to be registered in GAC.